# how to implement adwhirl in iphone app?

Tags: ios4, adwhirl, ads

I need to implement adwhirl advertisement in my iphone app.I don't how to use adwhirl.I searched but I couldn't do anything. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

you can download best tutorial of AdWhirl here 
[Tutorial](https://adwhirl-with-iad.googlecode.com/files/AdWhirl_pro.zip)